# YOLO Object Detection with distance measurement and audio feedback

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, yolo

We are newbie in the field of programming and we want to learn more, or you could help us code, learn more about YOLO (real-time object detection) with distance measurement from the camera to the object. Also we want the output to be in the form of audio. For example, a car has been detected and there will be an audio recording saying "A car has been detected at a distance of ...cm.

Comment: YOLO has nothing to do with distance measurement. You should study more about your projects then ask about the details here.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches. One would be to train the YOLO network to output the distance to the detected object along with the outher outputs. This might be well hard and time consuming, especially if you are new to this DNN stuff. Another, easier, way would be to get the bounding box size from the YOLO detections, and calculate the distance based on the known car size against the bounding box size (the smaller is the bounding box -- the farther is the car).

Don't expect `cm` precision with all this, you'd be lucky if you get your precision within 10%, that's 10m for 100m distance.